# Arranging fieldset elements like a typical table-design

Tags: html, css, tabular, fieldset

I'm trying to arrange the titles for 3 fieldset elements the same way a typical table looks, but I can't get it the way I want. This comes pretty close, however...

```
<label style="vertical-align:top;">Title1</label>
<fieldset style="display:inline; border:none; padding:0px; margin:0px; vertical-align:middle;">
<input value="Lorem Ipsum" /><br />
<input value="Lorem Ipsum" /><br />
<input value="Lorem Ipsum" />
</fieldset>

<label style="vertical-align:top;">Title2</label>
<fieldset style="display:inline; border:none; padding:0px; margin:0px; vertical-align:middle;">
<input value="Lorem Ipsum" />
</fieldset>

<label style="vertical-align:top;">Title3</label>
<fieldset style="display:inline; border:none; padding:0px; margin:0px; vertical-align:middle;">
Lorem Ipsum
</fieldset>
```

I may've used tables if there was a way I didn't have to run an if statement in my PHP code for both the title and the fieldset element. Plus, using fieldset for what I'm doing here seems to be a better alternative, in terms of pretty code.

Got any suggestions for anything similar to the code above?
Clarification: http://anony.ws/di-FJKD.jpg

Comment: What is it NOT doing that you want it to do?   Do you have like an image or example of what you want the end result to be like?  I'd like to help you out but I'm not sure what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: There is a picture. Right at the end of the post.

Comment: As I said; it's cleaner, and I won't have to run an if statement for the same thing, twice. It's redundant.

Comment: Labels are for input controls. Use `legend` instead, and place them inside the fieldset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you could do is remove the `label`'s from the flow so they don't get vertically aligned with the inputs/text.. do this by absolutely positioning them.. this will require a parent element to have `position: relative;` on it - I presume the overall code above is in a `form element` but for the sake a demo I've just wrapped all your code in a div.

#### [Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/HH5p2/)

HTML:

```
<div id="form"> 

  <label>Title1</label>
  <fieldset>
    <input value="Lorem Ipsum" /><br />
    <input value="Lorem Ipsum" /><br />
    <input value="Lorem Ipsum" />
  </fieldset>

  <label>Title2</label>
  <fieldset>
    <input value="Lorem Ipsum" />
  </fieldset>

  <label>Title3</label>
  <fieldset>
  Lorem Ipsum
  </fieldset>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#form {
  position: relative; /* labels need this on the their parent element */
}

fieldset {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding-top: 30px; /* leave a space to position for the labels */
}

fieldset {display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;}
fieldset {display: inline !ie7; /* IE6/7 need display inline after the inline-block rule */}

label {
   position: absolute; 
   top: 5px; 
   left: auto; 
   margin-left: 5px; 
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

---

**added** per comments

because there's not enough room in comments, here's the code I was thinking which doesn't position the `label`, to do this the `label`  would need to go inside the vertically aligned fieldset

```
#form {
  position: relative; /* labels need this on the their parent element */
}

fieldset {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

fieldset {display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; background: #eee;}
fieldset {display: inline !ie7;}


label {
   display: block;
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

HTML:

```
<fieldset>
  <label>Title1</label>
  <input value="Lorem Ipsum" /><br />
  <input value="Lorem Ipsum" /><br />
  <input value="Lorem Ipsum" />
</fieldset>


<fieldset>
  <label>Title2</label>
  <input value="Lorem Ipsum" />
</fieldset>


<fieldset>
  <label>Title3</label>
  Lorem Ipsum
</fieldset>
```

Comment: +1 But inline-block isn't necessary. Inline works fine, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/2Ds6j/2/)

Comment: so it isn't thanks!, so no need for IE hack either.. sorry was working on another way of doing it that would have meant the HTML be rewritten, forgot the change it back to basics - however if you wanted a width on the fieldset inline-block would possibly be the better option..

Comment: Is there no way I can align the text above the fieldset tags without using an absolute positioning? I'm not exactly looking to have an exact position of the text; I just want the text above the fieldset elements.

Comment: you could move the labels inside the fieldset, and make them `display:block;` without the positioning and extra padding.

Comment: I'm trying `display:block;` for `<legend>` but it isn't really working as expected. Is there something I'm missing? I removed the `position:absolute;` and `padding:1.25em;` codes.

Comment: `legends` are a pain, I was still working with `label` **inside** the `fieldset` though admittedly `label` is likely the wrong element and I'd be inclined to use a `h4` element or something, in which case that's a natural block element anyway.. have added code to answer

Comment: I think you may've misunderstood. I want the titles at the top of the elements, just like it would look like in a table. I just didn't want to use absolute positioning, because the position of the elements could differ, and thus the titles' position would have to differ as well.

Comment: I did wonder about your second question ;) - so you do only want it to look like my first answer, but without the positioning?.. hmm not sure about that, with a table that would take two rows to achieve. Ok so can you give a sample of where my first answer fails for you.. is it that the fieldsets could go over to "rows"?

Comment: The thing is, that if I use absolute positioning, it would add the titles at the very top of the page, and that is definitely not what I want to do. I'm using this code: http://jsfiddle.net/sKgcs/ , see how the titles collapse with the other content? That's why I don't want to use absolute positioning.

Comment: AH OK, you missed the bit in the answer about wrapping all of fieldsets in an element (`div#form`) though you maybe have an existing `form` element, make this element `position:relative;` this along with the top padding means the title stays relative to the actual "row" rather than going over your main content: **however** where this will still fall down is if the "rows" go over to two lines (narrow the window) - http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/7Qk5d - I've changed the titles to `h4` in this example if you try to replace that with `legend` you'll see what I mean by `legends` being a pain!

Answer (score 2):

Like this

```css
    .divTable {
      display: table;
      width: 50%;
    }
    .divRow {
      display: table-row;
    }
    .cellOne,
    .cellTwo {
      display: table-cell;
      padding: 20px;
      width: 30%;
    }
```

```html
<fieldset id="fileConnSet">
  <legend>File:</legend>
  <div class="divTable">
    <!--Table start-->
    <div class="divRow">
      <!--1st row, like <tr>-->
      <div class="cellOne">
        <!--1st column, like <td>-->
        <label>Name:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="cellTwo">
        <!--2nd column-->
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="divRow">
      <!--2nd row, like <tr>-->
      <div class="cellOne">
        <label>Age:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="cellTwo">
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="divRow">
      <!--3rd row, like <tr>-->
      <div class="cellOne">
        <label>Company:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="cellTwo">
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Table end-->
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Some explanation would be nice