# Applying `display: table` and `display: table-cell` to <fieldset> not working in Chrome / IE Edge

Tags: html, css

In Firefox this code renders Test and Test2 side-by-side, but in Chrome and IE Edge they are stacked vertically. Which is correct? And how can I make them side-by-side as in Firefox.

Code is as follows:

```css
.grid,
.row,
.column,
.cell {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.column {
  vertical-align: top;
}
.row {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.half {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class='row'>
  <legend class=title>Foo</legend>
  <fieldset class='cell half'>
    <legend class=subtitle>bar</legend>
    Test
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class='cell half'>
    <legend>baz</legend>
    Test2
  </fieldset>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In Firefox this code renders Test and Test2 side-by-side, but in Chrome and IE Edge they are stacked. Which is correct?

Based on these facts:

- the row has a `width: 100%`,
- there are two table cells, each with `width: 50%`,
- the box model is set to `box-sizing: border-box`, and
- margin spacing is set to 0

...it would appear that Firefox renders the layout correctly. Firefox aligns the table cells on the same row but Chrome wraps them onto two rows.

***Except that `fieldset` is a special type of element.***

`fieldset` doesn't accept changes to its `display` value like most other HTML elements. In fact, specifying `display: table`, `display: table-cell` or even `display: flex` to `fieldset`, will render elements unpredictably and unreliably.

> And how can I make them side-by-side as in Firefox.

If you want to alter `display` values, you'll need to use elements other than `fieldset` or nest `div` / `span` elements as containers within `fieldset`.

For more details and workarounds see here:

- [Fieldset does not support display: table / table-cell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9203561/3597276)
- [Arranging fieldset elements like a typical table-design](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6234299/3597276)
- [Default CSS values for a fieldset <legend>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3973456/3597276)
- [Why do <fieldset>s clear floats?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6481944/3597276)
- [Bug 949476 - CSS display property flex does not work on fieldset element](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=949476)

Answer (score 0):

you can try adding float:left to class `.half` eg.

```
.half {
  width: 50%; float:left;
}
```

Comment: That's what I don't want to do though, that's the intention of table and table-cell